# Break default layout of css float and clear

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I have four divs like these sizes, and they are in a main container with certain width. If I only set float left for each div, they will be showed like this:

```
##########################################################
#                          ##             ##             #
#                          ##             ##             #
#            5             ##      6      ##      7      #
#                          ##             ##             #
#                          ##             ##             #
##########################################################
############################
#                          #
#                          #
#                          #
#                          #
#            8             #
#                          #
#                          #
#                          #
#                          #
#                          #
############################
```

now i want them to be like following, without putting them in another container, how to make it works?

```
#########################################################
#                           ##                          #
#                           ##                          #
#            5              ##                          #
#                           ##                          #
#                           ##            8             #
##############################                          #
##############################                          #
#             ##            ##                          #
#             ##            ##                          #
#      6      ##      7     ##                          #  
#             ##            ##                          #  
#             ##            ##                          #
#########################################################
```

Comment: can we see your code??

Comment: temporary in here: http://www.emoceanstudios.com.au/portfolio.php

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want them wrapped by another container div?

Comment: they are actually generated by some functions, it's not easy to modify that

Comment: Gotcha, if that is the case then I think the poster that mentioned floating them to the right was somewhat on track, if that was still not good, then perhaps you might consider using fixed positioning. Obviously what would work best is having a wrapper div, THEN floating those inside the wrapper, but as you mentioned, it is not going to be easy to modify that.

Comment: actually, floating them to the right solved the problem, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

try this method u wil hav to giv float left for sum of the divs.

```
    <div id="main">
<!-- Wrapper for divs 5, 6 & 7 -->
     <div id="567">
      <div id="5"></div>
<!-- Wrapper for divs 6 & 7 -->
      <div id="67">
       <div id="6"></div>
       <div id="7"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="8"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I understand what you're doing with your markup there, but posting invalid markup is bad for others trying to understand what is going on.

Comment: see itz just and overview for it i purposly had put dat so that he wil understand which div goes whr according to his naming.

Comment: You can try <div id="main"> and also the use of comments like this, for example: <!-- Wrapper for divs 5, 6 & 7 --> I know it's an oversight, but it's good in practice I think.

Comment: actually, floating them to the right solved the problem, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try to order divs like this and play with floats:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="div div-8">Content #8</div>
    <div class="div div-5">Content #5</div>
    <div class="div div-7">Content #7</div>
    <div class="div div-6">Content #6</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main div {float: right;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v6RR5/2/

Comment: If it helps consider upvoting the answer or/and accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to get the result as you wanted. This might not be the best way to do it since I assign a height to the block. You can play around [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/qiqiabaziz/8CmTP/3/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="five">5</div>
    <div class="eight">8</div>
    <div class="six">6</div>
    <div class="seven">7</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.five{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    background: #666;    
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;    
}
.eight{
    float:right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 350px;
    line-height: 350px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;  
}
.six, .seven{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px; 
}
.six{background: #ccc;}
.seven{background: #999;}
```